# How can I index (search) trought mysql database and to find best values of every column?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

So, I have 14-15 columns  (Username, Password, location ) .... and every column has his own user data's.

I want to make a search, echoing those data's in the descending way

Exemple:  Column  AGE.

John has age 10
Jahon has age 14
Loku has age 20.

I want to echo echo "age" by the highest number

How can this be achieved?

I want to make a top 10 age list,  and I want to make them descreasing

List will look like:

1. Loku: ?php echo $Loku Age?>
2. Jahon: ?php echo $Jahons Age?>
3. John: ?php echo $Johns age?>.

but when database updates, the values from list will change too, even usernames.

How? thank you.

Comment: Look up the `ORDER BY` statement in the [MySQL Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Comment: And how can I index them to search for all of the users, not only by one?

Comment: Look up the `LIMIT` clause in the [MySQL Manual](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx)

Comment: Maybe you should just spend a few hours doing a Basic MySQL tutorial and reading the manual

Comment: For best results from Stack Overflow, you should include an example of your input data and desired output. Please [edit] your question. What do you want to do if multiple people in your table have the same age as one another?

Comment: You make a `SELECT` over the _whole_ table and then pick results one by one to output them. So only a single query for _all_ records.

Comment: How much [research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @O.Jones if they have the same age, taking by Username's alphabetical decrease.

Comment: @RiggsFolly actually i am researching, i'm reading from w3schools, i understand it, but I don't know how to echo those values.

Comment: Oh Please pick another source for your research

Comment: Friends don't let friends use w3schools. Too many inaccuracies.

Comment: If i use sort($tablename) would be fine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select (username, age) FROM table ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 10
```

This way, you select two columns from your table, which is the name of a user and their age.
The result should be 10 users with the highest age.
Try the following data fetch process to retrieve existing data from the database:

```
Create a connection to MySQL (use your username, password and database name for that, again, read a tutorial)
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

Select the data:

$sql = (SELECT (username, age) FROM table ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 10);
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo $row['username'] . " - " . $row['age'] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: <?php

 include('config.php');
 session_start();
 $sql = "Select (username, age) FROM table ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 10";
?> 

<div style="text"> <?php> echo $sql ?> </div>


is this the correct way to use it?

Comment: Completely not. Please consult a SQL tutorial, like https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: Despite others saying it's not a reliable source, it is. There's nothing wrong with it and if you stumble upon something not working, you can always look it up online. Also you must change the column names and a table name according to your table.

Comment: Find a tutorial for fetching SQL data from the database in PHP online. I updated my answer. You could try to use the fetching process I added to my answer. However, how to output them in HTML and everything, decide for yourself by using online resources.

Comment: What I've managed  to do while reading tutorials.  jsfiddle.net/trqwgv53/6/

Comment: Nope. In a while loop, you're just overwriting the two variables over and over again until the loop stops. You should use an array in a global session variable (look it up) to store all the data. Then, output each array member in HTML with PHP code. Also I don't think JSFiddle supports PHP,  but JavaScript, which is different.